# python - need help inserting text files with open() into mysql

Tags: python

Can someone help me out with the mysql connection statement to instert a textfile into a mysql table (field type is long blob)?

For example:

```
cursor.execute("insert into mytable (file_contents) values ('"+open(filename,"r").read()+"')")
```

Obviously that's not very practical, can someone post a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dangerous to append content of a file directly into an SQL query, because of special characters (quotes!) or malicious SQL commands.

Try this:

```
with open(filename,"r") as infile:
    cursor.execute("insert into mytable (file_contents) values (%s)", (infile.read(), ))
```

Comment: Exactly. Note that the data from infile is passed as second argument -- the string interpolation is handled by cursor.execute which also makes sure that the string parameters are correctly escaped.